# Magento EE 1.13 - static block permissions based on customer segment or attribute

Tags: ee-1.13, permissions

I need to restrict access to certain product categories and product information for some of my customers in a particular store.

I would like to be able to set up a custom attribute on my customer, and based on that attribute's value, control what product categories and products are displayed, what CMS pages are available from the menu, and control whether a static block would be displayed or not if added to a CMS page.

I purchased an extension to control access to a CMS page, but it doesn't control the cms page menus.

Is there a way to do this with magento EE?

It seems like the customer segment infrastructure should be able to at least provide a way of defining which customers see which sets of information, but there doesn't seem to be a way to tie the segments to product / CMS content.

Comment: Doesn't this describe Enterprise Banners almost perfectly?

Comment: Is it possible to embed the banner inside of CMS page, and will the customer segmentation logic only display that banner for customers who are in the segment?

Comment: You can place a Widget anywhere within any page at all using the Widget panel. Ping me privately and I can walk you through. philwinkle at gmail.

Comment: Can you put your answer (If you solved it) to close out this post